# What are my options after a road rage incident?

Tags: united-states, police, traffic

I was in an incident today where a driver cut me off and slammed on his brakes to attempt to make me rear end him. After this he got out of his car, yelled at me, told me to come out of mine and fight. I remained in my car and then started calling 911 when it was clear he wasn’t leaving. He saw me on the phone so he started to leave but threw a rock which hit my window first before leaving. Unfortunately I have no video evidence. I did get a picture of the license plate and the man’s back.

I filed a police report and they called me and told me they made contact with the driver and he admitted to everything except throwing the rock.

What are my options?

If I press the charges what could he be charged with, since he didn’t admit to the rock throwing and it’s my word against his? If I’m willing to pay the legal fees, would he have to pay them back if I won the case? Will he know my personal information such as name and address if I press charges? And finally, I don’t want to waste the police’s time, but I do think this menace should face consequences. Is it typical to press charges in a case like this or would the police view it as wasting their time?

Comment: If you want to press charges it goes to the DA and the State takes care of charging him, you don't pay for that. If you are suing him in small claims (or other court) then you would pay for that. Are you talking about a criminal case (State lays criminal charges), or a civil one (you sue for damages)?

Comment: @RonBeyer thanks for explaining. I’m not sure, the damages to the window are minimal thankfully, I’m more concerned about his aggressive driving and threatening me. So I guess criminal?

Comment: What he could be charged with depends on the State. Many States have road rage laws. Whatever it is, it would probably just be a misdemeanor if the DA decides to pursue.

Comment: @RonBeyer thanks so much. Since the state would press charges, would he learn any personal information about me? I’m worried about retribution afterwards